# Pointer Events: None Not working in IOs

Tags: ios, css, object, svg, responsive-design

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/uke23/5/)

When SVG image is clicked, alert function does not trigger in IPhone. (It works in android).

How can I make this workin IPhone **without using z-index and overlay div**?

**HTML**

```
<div  id="svg" style="position: relative; background: green; width: 900px; height: 900px;" >
<object id="object" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://www.useragentman.com/tests/pointerEvents/images/tv-path.svg">
</object>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#svg object{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#svg').on('click', function () {
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @Johnny, I barely even remember this issue and I don't remember how it ended. Sorry.